# TypeError: 'unicode' does not have the buffer interface

Tags: python, unicode, interface, flask, buffer

Please tell me how to fix it. I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'unicode' does not have the buffer interface
```

Comment: Please give us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want us to help fix your code. If we can't see what you've written, we can only guess at the many ways you might have written something wrong, which makes it impossible to debug anything; all we can do is give very general hints.

Comment: there is everything        https://github.com/icefromtexas/sched

Comment: A complete program is not an MCVE. Read the link. Also, your question has to be meaningful on its own, not rely on comments—or, worse, on links that may change or disappear in the future—to be answerable. Read the rest of the help.

Comment: just a note `b'something'` vs `u'something'` vs `'something'`

Answer (score 13):

You've got a `unicode` string. You're trying to call a function that requires `str`-like types (`str`, `bytearray`, anything else that supports the buffer interface). So you get an error, just like you'd get if you tried to call a function that required number-like types.

Most likely the problem is that you either (a) need to `encode` your `unicode` to `str`, or (b) need to call a function that takes `unicode` instead of `str`. But without seeing any of your code, it's very hard to give a more specific answer.

I can give you two general pieces of advice that might help:

1. Read the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). If you don't understand it, ask for help, and keep reading until you understand the whole thing, and the answer to this question is obvious.
2. Use Python 3.x instead of 2.x. It won't magically solve all of your problems, but you'll generally have fewer mixing-Unicode-and-non-Unicode-strings problems, and they'll generally be more obvious (mainly because you'll generally only be dealing with Unicode strings).

Comment: Thanks! I just don't understand how this error appeared because before I used the same code and there was no errors...

Comment: @HeyYep: Since you haven't shown us the code you used, it's impossible to do more than guess. But I'm guessing that, if it really is "the same code", you had `str` inputs last time, and `unicode` inputs this time, and therefore it didn't work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a flask tag. There was a bug in `werkzeug` with this error message. So update to the newest version and you should be fine.